# aiohttp._http_parser.HttpParser.feed_data aiohttp.http_exceptions.BadHttpMessage: 400, message='too many header bytes seen; overflow detected'

Tags: python-3.x, aiohttp

I am trying to send an HTTP request with a JWT token using Postman, I saw this error when the size of token is over 80k. I've already tried to set the max_field_size and max_line_size as below:

app = web.Application(
handler_args={
'max_field_size': 1024 ** 2,
'max_line_size': 1024 **2
}
)

I'm using python 3.6.2 and aiohttp 3.6.2.